# Weird netcat (OpenBSD version) behavior

Tags: command-line, server, netcat

I am using Ubuntu server 16.04.3, it comes with the OpenBSD version of netcat.

I have used the OpenBSD version of netcat before in Fedora, and in Fedora I can't use the `-p` option with the `-l` option, for example the following is illegal:

```
nc -l -p 12345
```

But in Ubuntu server 16.04.3, the above command worked (by "worked", I mean netcat started listening)!

Even though `man nc` on Ubuntu server 16.04.3 itself says that it is illegal:

[image]

Why is this happening?!

Comment: What do you mean the command above _worked_ exactly? It ignored the `-p` option and went on listening? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @dobey I edited my question.

Comment: The traditional version of `nc` requires the `-p` flag. Without it, it ignores the port number and uses a random high port to listen on.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 version: BSD and GNU. The GNU version support -l with -p (or at least does state you can used them together). The man page states we use an edited BSD version.

This is from the GNU version:

```
NAME

netcat - GNU Netcat Manual 

CONTENTS

SYNOPSIS

    netcat [options] hostname port [port] ...

    netcat -l -p port [options] [hostname] [port] ...

    netcat -L hostname:port -p port [options] ...
```

===

This is from the BSD man page:

```
Name

nc - arbitrary TCP and UDP connections and listens
Synopsis

nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] 
     [-i interval [-p source_port] 
     [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout]
     [-X proxy_protocol] [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname[port[s]]

...

-l' Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming 
connection rather than initiate a connection to a remote host. 
It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z options. 
Additionally, any timeouts specified with the -w 
option are ignored.
```

Weird indeed. But it looks like we use either the GNU where the manual page points to the original BSD manual or we use an altered BSD version and also with the wrong manual page.

Comment: *"There are 2 version: BSD and GNU"* Do you mean Ubuntu server has 2 netcat versions, or are you talking in general?

Comment: We have 2 packages netstat-traditional and netstat-openBSD (1st is the original BSD and the other the altered BSD version) and there is netstat gnu (I believe only as a TAR download available ). So in this context it was meant as "general".