# How to create a bash listener with netcat in Ubuntu?

Tags: netcat

In a lot of basic security tutorials and [materials](https://www.sans.org/security-resources/posters/netcat-cheat-sheet/240/download) I see netcat used to open a listener / backdoor shell. On port 666 for example:

```
netcat -l -p 1666 -e /bin/bash/
```

How to do this in Ubuntu? When I try I get the error `nc: invalid option -- 'e'`. Running `man nc` or `man netcat`  confirms that the -e option is not available but there is a rather complicated workaround.

```
     There is no -c or -e option in this netcat, but you still can execute a command after connection being established by redirect‐
 ing file descriptors. Be cautious here because opening a port and let anyone connected execute arbitrary command on your site
 is DANGEROUS. If you really need to do this, here is an example:

 On ‘server’ side:

       $ rm -f /tmp/f; mkfifo /tmp/f
       $ cat /tmp/f | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 > /tmp/f

 On ‘client’ side:

       $ nc host.example.com 1234
       $ (shell prompt from host.example.com)
```

Based on [the answer to a related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982450/weird-netcat-openbsd-version-behavior) I think I may need to invoke the GNU version of netcat but I'm not sure how. I installed the `netcat-traditional` package, but `nc`, `netcat` both still invoke the BSD version and variants I've tried like `netcat-traditional` don't seem to be valid commands. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS if that matters.

So while I have a workaround, I think what I'd really like to know is the easiest way to run the traditional netcat in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Ports 1-1023 are "privileged", in that they may be used only by the `root` (`UID=0`) processes. Your example was probably assuming `root`.

Try `-p 1666`. Or, `sudo`, if you want to export a `root` shell..

Comment: Thanks for this... I've made some edits to clarify that the issue is that the `-e` option is not available. To your point I did just verify right now that `nc -l -p 666` fails with a permission issue, but changing the port to `1666` or adding `sudo` both work (as long as I leave out the `-e` option).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with three alternatives for netcat. Run `/usr/lib/command-not-found --ignore-instaled nc` to show their packages. (`/usr/lib/command-not-found` is from the `command-not-found` package, which should be installed by default on desktop installs.):

```
Command 'nc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install netcat-openbsd      # version 1.218-4ubuntu1, or
sudo apt install netcat-traditional  # version 1.10-47
sudo apt install ncat                # version 7.91+dfsg1+really7.80+dfsg1-2ubuntu0.1
```

Install whichever version you want (both traditional and ncat have the `-e` option, my guess is that openbsd removed it because it is a big security footgun), then run `update-alternatives --config nc` to set the default.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with three alternatives for netcat. Run `/usr/lib/command-not-found --ignore-instaled nc` to show their packages. (`/usr/lib/command-not-found` is from the `command-not-found` package, which should be installed by default on desktop installs.):

```
Command 'nc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install netcat-openbsd      # version 1.218-4ubuntu1, or
sudo apt install netcat-traditional  # version 1.10-47
sudo apt install ncat                # version 7.91+dfsg1+really7.80+dfsg1-2ubuntu0.1
```

Install whichever version you want (both traditional and ncat have the `-e` option, apparently openbsd removed it because it is a big security footgun), then run `update-alternatives --config nc` to set the default.